# Restrict method parameter of string type to const field from one given class

Tags: c#, resharper, postsharp

Let's say we have some method

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public Sth GetByKey(string key) 
    {
        //not important
    }
}

static class SomeKeys
{
    public static string Abc = "Abc";
    public static string Xyz = "Xyz";
}
```

and it **can't** by changed. Is there a relatively easy way to restrict values passed to this method to fields from class `SomeKeys` in some projects? So `a.GetByKey("Qwerty")` and `a.GetByKey("Abc")` would generate some warning or error and `a.GetByKey(SomeKeys.Abc)` wouldn't.

I know it's a bad design and so on and I don't search for a way to refactor this. Right now I'm mostly curious if it is possible. I was thinking about writing some postsharp magic but i don't know if it's worth the trouble. It could show error during compilation or it may be some magic rule in resharper or something else completely.

**Edit**
Also i don't want to change calls to `GetByKey`, parameter type must be a string.

Comment: Make SomeKeys an `enum` type.

Comment: What can't be changed exactly? `SomeClass`? `SomeKeys`? Both?

Comment: @Clemens, yes this is good way of doing that. I want/can changed that

Comment: @InBetween `SomeKeys` could look different, it is just example class. I want `GetByKey` with string parameter and some non-hardcoded string as parameter, for example from static field from class (one concrete class)

Comment: You could use PostSharp's reflection serach - see http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch.

Answer (score 3):

No refactoring or change needed to the original class, simply create a wrapper class over SomeClass (NewSomeClass) that takes care of being strongly typed, start using NewSomeClass everywhere. Way easier than implementing some Roslyn/Resharper trick that you would need to deploy to your whole team.

```
public class NewSomeClass 
{
    private SomeClass inner;

    private NewSomeClass(SomeClass inner)
    {
      this.inner = inner;
    }

    public Sth GetByKey(SomeKey key) 
    {
        return this.inner.GetByKey(key.Value);
    }
}

public sealed class SomeKey
{    
   SomeKey(string val)
   {
      this.Value = val;
   }
   public string Value {get;}

   public static readonly SomeKey Abc = new SomeKey("Abc");

   public static readonly SomeKey Xyz = new SomeKey("Xyz");
}
```

Comment: the constructor for `SomeKey` should be private and the class sealed.

Comment: This is of course good solution but I don't want to change calls to GeyByKey(string). If i could/want to do that then I wouldn't ask about funky solution. If you want some reasoning lets say that for example that it's breaking change.I will edit question i a second.

Comment: Please have a more precise question, upfront I can tell you it is possible with a custom Roslyn analyzer, and that does answer your question :) See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29241013/6775223 for similar example. Considering this is compile time validation, it would mean that only const or direct local values with the supported strings would be possible to validate.